# How to set sudo password other than the user's own password?

Tags: sudo, root

For example, suppose I have a user `sysadm` with password `abcdefg`. But when it needs to execute `sudo` command, the password is `hijklmn`.

Is this doable?

Comment: Is this your question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94626/set-sudo-password-differently-from-login-one also this https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1650877